# Java - write text on the screen

Tags: java, canvas, lwjgl, slick2d

I am making a game with Java and LWJGL..
Basically I want to write my game's fps on the screen, but I really don't understand how i should do that.

I am thinking its something related to the Graphics class, am i right?

```
Graphics g = new Graphics();
g.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
g.setFont(new Font("Impact", Font.PLAIN, 20));
g.drawString(fps + " FPS", 20, 30);
g.dispose();
```

This code returns me an error..it says that the constructor of the graphics class isn't implemented right.

Any ideas?

Comment: Never used Slick2D, but if they have a Graphics class, it is more likely that you need to grab an existing copy of `Graphics` somewhere instead of creating your own.

Comment: I am really new to slick2D, so how can i know if it has a Graphics class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To draw, you need the draw handle for the original `Graphics` object and not by creating a new one yourself.

As far as I can tell, for a basic game, your controlling class should be extending `BasicGame` which provides a `render` method, from which you can grab a `Graphics` object.

See: [BasicGame](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/BasicGame.html) and [render](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Game.html#render%28org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer,%20org.newdawn.slick.Graphics%29)

I imagine what you need to do is override that method, like this:

```
public void render(GameContainer container, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    //grab graphics g here and use it.
}
```

For a basic template, look [here](http://thejavablog.wordpress.com/2008/06/08/using-slick-2d-to-write-a-game/).

Comment: thanks! but i think i don't have slick2D actually, the only libraries i am using are - LWJGL and slick-util.

Comment: Well that is a pain; was going off the Slick2D tag and the Slick2D syntax you were attempting to use. Nevermind.

Comment: If you want to continue using LWJGL and slick-util, see this tutorial: http://www.ninjacave.com/tutorials, specifically Slick-Util Library (Part 3 - TrueType Fonts for LWJGL)

Comment: its fine, i am using slick2D now, accepted your answer buddy !

Answer (score 0):

You can't just create new Graphics instance from scratch and hope it will draw what you want and where you want.

> Graphics contexts are obtained from other graphics contexts or are
>   created by calling getGraphics on a component.

If you want to put sime text on the screen with `LWJGL` then search exact and you will find a lot of solutions. Even on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9M5svhbMq8).